# call a function after all animations on the other function are done

Tags: jquery, function, animation

I have two functions, each of them have some animations. I want to call the second function when all animations on first function are done. I tried anything and as the animations inside function 1 have variable timing i cant use specific one to say when this one finishes all animations are done. It keep playing all animations at the same time. I'll be grateful if someone can help me.
this is my code:

```
function goToSubMenu1(subMenu1Id,currentPage,selectedButtonText){

    closeCurrentPage(subMenu1Id);
    openTargetPage(subMenu1Id,currentPage,selectedButtonText);
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------open page
function openTargetPage(subMenu1Id,currentPage,selectedButtonText){
    if(currentPage=='homePage'){
        toHomePageMini();
        subMenu1(subMenu1Id,selectedButtonText);
        pageInAnimation('homePage');
        pageInAnimation('subMunu1Container');
        $('#'+subMenu1Id).css({'display':'none'});
    }
    else{
        subMenu1(subMenu1Id,selectedButtonText);
        pageInAnimation('homePage');
        pageInAnimation('subMunu1Container');
        $('#'+subMenu1Id).css({'display':'none'});
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------close page
function closeCurrentPage(subMenu1Id){
    pageOutAnimation('homePage');
    pageOutAnimation('subMunu1Container');
    $('#'+subMenu1Id).css({'display':'block'});
}
```

Comment: You'll have to show us the animation functions, they would have to have a callback, return a promise or something similar to know when they have completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the correct way of doing this is to use a function callback, run code post execution.
This should be helpful:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.callbacks/

Another way is to use the `.each` method with jQuery - To make asynchronous execution, (With this method you'll have to make a selected list of your elements, ordered by your means)

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can assign a variable name (or not, using it as the below example) to a function and then give a timeline execution.

This can be done using the [`when() - then()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) pair.

For example:

```
$.when(function () {}).then(function () {});
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read your code, but if you want to achieve what you want, you can use [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function. If you know how long your first animation will take, just set parameter of `delay()` to any time longer than your first animation time, and it will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `.animate()` method, it provides a `complete` `callback` in its declaration